# DVD writer opens when booting PC

Tags: windows-8, dvd

Whenever I start my computer it opens the DVD writer tray. When I close it by pushing it back in, it repeats for a certain time. After that my computer starts normally. What could be causing this?

Comment: Sounds more like a bios / hardware problem than an OS one?

Comment: Is the DVD the first boot device in BIOS/UEFI?

Comment: @Utrecht Windows 8

Comment: @DrMoishePippik No, DVD is not the first boot device